# How to remove encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" from xml Document object in Java

Tags: java, xml, xmldocument

I want to create XML in Java.

```
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
     docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
```

but Java automatically creates declaration like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

How can I remove  `encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"` so it will be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133395/remove-xml-declaration-from-the-generated-xml-document-using-java

Comment: @JoachimSauer, I don't want to override encoding because other program uses this XML in a way I don't know. So I can't be sure what encoding I can set

Comment: @UmerHayat, no, that question about removing ALL XML declaration

Comment: @VextoR: **Any** tool that accepts XML **must** accept one with a valid encoding property (especially if the encoding specified is UTF-8). If your other tool doesn't accept that, then it's **broken**!

Comment: The values you are trying to remove are assumed (if the parser is following the rules in the XML specification) to be the default if they aren't specified, so removing them would make no difference!

Comment: UTF-8 is the default encoding of an XML document if there is no Byte-Order-Mark (BOM): http://www.opentag.com/xfaq_enc.htm#enc_default. This means that <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> or <?xml version="1.0"?> are equivalent declaration (without BOM).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there is no legal way to exclude theese attributes from generation.
But after it's generated you can use XSLT to remove this.

I think this is a good way.

Answer (score 15):

Why do you need to remove an encoding? But..

```
doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
```

will erase `standalone="no"`

Answer (score 12):

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

This would resolve your issue, verified at JDK 6

Comment: Dont understand the negative mark on the question. I had the same issue to create a BPEL file and there might be tons other reasons this is needed. So thank you for your answer. Would've taken me ages.