# NSXMLDocument : Remove standalone="no"

Tags: objective-c, nsxmldocument

I use NSXMLDocument to generate a xml string:

```
NSXMLDocument *doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc]init];
[doc setVersion:@"1.0"];
[doc setCharacterEncoding:@"UTF-8"];
```

its generating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
```

How i can remove 'standalone="no"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the [dokumentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002406-DontLinkElementID_5) there is no way to avoid it from being generated. In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511400/how-to-remove-encoding-utf-8-standalone-no-from-xml-document-object-in-java) it's also mentioned. But if you read the accepted answer of [Igor Konoplyanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71420/igor-konoplyanko) you can try to use `XSLT` to remove it. The linked question is about java but I think in objective-c there will be similar functions.