# What is the correct way of logging in an xml from two different classes ? For now I get an error in the xml produced

Tags: java, xml, logging, java.util.logging

By default the code :

```
class Tester {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName());
    FileHandler fHandler = new FileHandler("LOGGED.xml",true);
    logger.addHandler(fHandler);
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"This is an info log message");
    fHandler.close();
  }
}
```

produces a `xml` of the type :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
  <record>
    <date>2013-02-03T08:16:37</date>
    <millis>1359859597763</millis>
    <sequence>0</sequence>
    <logger>Tester</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>Tester</class>
    <method>main</method>
    <thread>1</thread>
    <message>This is an info log message</message>
 </record>
</log>
```

But if I try to append to the *xml* produced above, by the following code :

```
class Tester_1{
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Tester_1.class.getName());
        FileHandler fHandler = new FileHandler("LOGGED.xml",true);
        logger.addHandler(fHandler);
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"This is a custom message from my own formatter !");
        fHandler.close();
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

it appends the following to the previous *xml* produced :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
 <record>
   <date>2013-02-03T08:16:51</date>
   <millis>1359859611306</millis>
   <sequence>0</sequence>
   <logger>Tester_1</logger>
   <level>INFO</level>
   <class>Tester_1</class>
   <method>main</method>
   <thread>1</thread>
   <message>This is a custom message from my own formatter !</message>
 </record>
</log>
```

and when I try opening this *xml* in the browser,I get the following error :

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 27 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

What do I do to avoid the statements :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
```

two times ? I want *xml* with just the `log` tag appended to the end of the xml.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133395/remove-xml-declaration-from-the-generated-xml-document-using-java

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid xml headers completely in your log file, you can try this in your code

```
    FileHandler fHandler = new FileHandler("LOGGED.xml", true);
    fHandler.setFormatter(new XMLFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getHead(Handler h) {
            return "";
        }
    });
    logger.addHandler(fHandler);
```

Comment: When did I say I want to avoid headers ?

Comment: I said I want to append the log messages without the repetition of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">` How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The easies way to fix it is to configure FileHandler to generate a new file name each time you start your app, e.g.

```
new FileHandler("log%g.xml", 100000000, 10);
```

see API for details

Comment: They will not be deleted, FileHandler will create a new file each time

Answer (score 0):

The proposed patch is listed in RFE [JDK-4629315 : Appending of XML Logfiles doesn't merge new records.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4629315)  You might be able to extend XMLFormatter and override the `getHead` method to condtionally write the default head value or the empty string based off of the size (empty or full) of the target file.  Assuming you can compute the current file being used for logging.