# How to omit xml declaration from a xml using java

Tags: java, xml

How does one omit the xml declaration from using Java (any function)
 My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
       <Entity>RIM_BPS</Entity>
```

I need the output to be just

```
<Entity>RIM_BPS</Entity>
```

Comment: and why do you need to do that!how would other xml parsers determine the encoding if you remove that!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133395/remove-xml-declaration-from-the-generated-xml-document-using-java

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you intend to do this? Because xml document must have the declaration tag to be used for the xml parsers.
Well, in any case, if you need to still remove the tag line, you can do it by following the below mentioned simple steps:
1. Read the xml file in BufferedSteamReader
2. Open the Stream
3. Read it line by line and as you know the declaration tag will be the very first line of your xml (ignoring the spaces)
4. Ignore the first declaration tag line and then save all other lines in the file.

Or otherwise you can choose the Append flag to modify the already existing file.

I hope this will help.... If you still need help, let us know.

Thanks...
Mr.777